# display results from users input with API data using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, json, api

I'm new to jQuery, API, and HTML. The goal of my HTML page is to have the user enter the year and select the month from the drop-down. Then the "List Incidents" button will display the table based on the user's inputs. However, the table displays all results. Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thank you

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//populate dropdown
var val,
    text;
for (text in months) {
    val = months[text];
    $('<option/>').val(val).text(text).appendTo($('#months'));
}
// List incidents Button
$("#getButton").click(function() {
    getData();


});
});
function makeURL(year, month){
let base = "https://moto.data.socrata.com/resource/jfwn-iu5d.json"
}

function getData() {
var year = $('#year').val();
//    var month = $('#months').val();
var url = "https://moto.data.socrata.com/resource/jfwn-iu5d.json";

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    Type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data:{
       month: month,
        year: year,
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("success");
        var data = data.filter(a=> (new 
Date(a.incident_datetime).getMonth()+1) === parseInt(month) && new 
 Date(a.incident_datetime).getFullYear() === parseInt(year));

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            crime = data[i];
            var dateTime = crime["incident_datetime"];
            var dateInfo = new Date(dateTime);
            var date = calendarDate(dateInfo);
            var day = crime["day_of_week"];
            var time = timeStamp(dateInfo);
            var description = crime["incident_description"];
            var description = descriptionSelection(description)
            var tableRow = "<tr><td>" + date + "</td><td>" + day + "</td> 
 <td>" + time + "</td><td>" + description + "</td></tr>";
            $("#output").append(tableRow);
        }
    }
});
}


// Function to only display descriptions of incidents
function descriptionSelection(description) {
description = description.split("P:")[0];
return description;
}

// Function to display time
function timeStamp(dateInfo) {
var time = dateInfo.toLocaleTimeString(undefined, {
    hour: "2-digit",
    minute: "2-digit",
});
return time;
}

// Function to display MMM/DD/YYYY
 function calendarDate(dateInfo) {
var date = dateInfo.toLocaleDateString("en-US", {
    month: "short",
    day: "numeric",
    year: "numeric"
});
return date;
}

var days={
'Select Month': '',
'Monday' : 'Monday',
'Tuesday' : 'Tuesday'
}   ;
// map containing months
var months = {
'Select Month': '',
'January': 'JAN',
'February': 'FEB',
'March': 'Mar',
'April': 'APR',
'May': 'MAY',
'June': 'JUN',
'July': 'JUL',
'August': 'AUG',
'September': 'SEP',
'October': 'OCT',
'November': 'NOV',
'December': 'DEC'
};
```

HTML:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink- 
to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384- 
Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
 crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/worcester.css">
<title> Worcester Crime Report</title>
</head>

<body>
<main role="main" class="container-fluid">

    <!--Navigation bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light ">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href='#'>
            <img src="image/Worcester_logo.png" width="30" height="30" 
class="d-linline-block align-top" alt="">
             City of Worcester</a>

        <!-- Toggler/ collapsible Button-->
        <div>
            <button type="button" id="navButton" class="navbar-toggle" data- 
toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"> </span>
            </button>
        </div>


        <!--- Navigation bar links --->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Crime Data</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="crimeStats.html">Crime 
 Stats</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" target="_blank" 
href='https://www.crimereports.com/agency/worcesterma#!/dashboard?'
                        Police Department </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <br>
    <h2> Crime Record in Worcester, MA </h2>
    <br>
    <p>This app provides a list of crimes with dates and times of the 
occurrances in Worcester, Massachusetts.</p>

    <!---Search year and months --->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <input type="number"class="form-control" placeholder="Year YYYY" 
id="year" min="2011">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <select name="months" class="form-control" id="months">
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            <button type="button" id="getButton" class="btn btn-info">List 
 Incidents</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="error"></div>

    <br>
    <div class="overflow-x:auto">
        <table class=" table table-hover" id="output">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Day</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <br>

</main>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256- 
FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
</script>

<script src="scripts/w2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add your HTML too

Comment: We don't have all your JavaScript code, and we need your HTML code.

Comment: I just posted the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many things going wrong here,

1. Months binding not proper
2. you are not applying any filters into result
3. You need to adjust this changes according to your requirement.

I have added comments to the changes you can take a look at the demo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

//populate dropdown
var val,
    text;
    var index =1;
for (text in months) {

    val = months[text];
    $('<option/>').val(index).text(text).appendTo($('#months'));
    index++;
}
// List incidents Button
$("#getButton").click(function() {
    getData();


});
});
function makeURL(year, month){
let base = "https://moto.data.socrata.com/resource/jfwn-iu5d.json"
}

function getData() {
var year = $('#year').val();
var month = $('#months').val();
var url = "https://moto.data.socrata.com/resource/jfwn-iu5d.json";

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    Type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",    
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("success");
        var data = data.filter(a=> (new 
Date(a.incident_datetime).getMonth()+1) === parseInt(month) && new 
 Date(a.incident_datetime).getFullYear() === parseInt(year));

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            crime = data[i];
            var dateTime = crime["incident_datetime"];
            var dateInfo = new Date(dateTime);
            var date = calendarDate(dateInfo);
            var day = crime["day_of_week"];
            var time = timeStamp(dateInfo);
            var description = crime["incident_description"];
            var description = descriptionSelection(description)
            var tableRow = "<tr><td>" + date + "</td><td>" + day + "</td><td>" + time + "</td><td>" + description + "</td></tr>";
            $("#output").append(tableRow);
        }
    }
});
}


// Function to only display descriptions of incidents
function descriptionSelection(description) {
description = description.split("P:")[0];
return description;
}

// Function to display time
function timeStamp(dateInfo) {
var time = dateInfo.toLocaleTimeString(undefined, {
    hour: "2-digit",
    minute: "2-digit",
});
return time;
}

// Function to display MMM/DD/YYYY
 function calendarDate(dateInfo) {
var date = dateInfo.toLocaleDateString("en-US", {
    month: "short",
    day: "numeric",
    year: "numeric"
});
return date;
}

var days={
'Select Month': '',
'Monday' : 'Monday',
'Tuesday' : 'Tuesday'
}   ;
// map containing months
var months = {
'Select Month': '',
'January': 'JAN',
'February': 'FEB',
'March': 'Mar',
'April': 'APR',
'May': 'MAY',
'June': 'JUN',
'July': 'JUL',
'August': 'AUG',
'September': 'SEP',
'October': 'OCT',
'November': 'NOV',
'December': 'DEC'
};
```

```html
Try month:01 year:2017
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main role="main" class="container-fluid">   

    <!---Search year and months --->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
        Year:
            <input type="number"class="form-control" placeholder="Year YYYY" 
id="year" min="2011">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
        Month:
            <select name="months" class="form-control" id="months">
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            <button type="button" id="getButton" class="btn btn-info">List 
 Incidents</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="error"></div>

    <br>
    <div class="overflow-x:auto">
        <table class=" table table-hover" id="output">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Day</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <br>

</main>
```

Comment: Hi. The following is my full js code, I added what you suggested as well. I didn't think it was needed earlier. The results didn't display.

Comment: sorry. I justed edited my posting with the full code. This is my first time using stackOverflow. Please bare with me. Thanks for your help. I added your suggestions, the table doesn't display any data.

Comment: @Madeline I have updated my answer, please have a look carefully, it is very easy to implement now.

Comment: I was able to log a "success" twice but still no data shown table

Comment: Which month and year? check received result in console and apply filter according to that, ti should work

Comment: I tried for January 2017. The console display "JAN" and "2017",  but somehow nothing is displayed on the table.

Comment: Check my answer, https://imgur.com/a/q2x6Fr0 there are results filtered

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! I missed a line.

Comment: The data goes all the way to March 2011, but it seems to only filter the first page, which is up to 2016. Is there anyway I can loop through the whole data? Thank you

Comment: I noticed that the search is "january 2017" but the result is "february 2017" . Also, the data goes all the way to March 2011, but it seems to only filter the first page, which is up to 2016. Is there anyway I can loop through the whole data? Thank you

Comment: I was able to match the search month with the display. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to load only the year 2017?

Comment: You can modify it as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're not passing in the `year` and `month` variables into the URL. Since you're using a GET method, there are two ways you can do this. Since I'm not familiar with the URL in question, I'm just guessing/assuming the endpoint and parameters.

Option 1, append to the URL.

```
var url = "https://moto.data.socrata.com/resource/jfwn-iu5d.json?month=" + month + "&year="+year;
```

Option 2, add it to the ajax call with the data function.

```
...
type: "GET",
data: {
    Month: month,
    Year: year,
},
...
```

**Assumptions**

- That you are wanting to pass in the `month` and `year` variables.
- That they accept the arguments `Month` and `Year`

Comment: If you just copied and pasted that code, it probably won't work - like what was mentioned, I don't know the URL parameters, so you will have to replace the Month and Year keys with what they accept. i.e.: `TheMonth: month, TheYear: year`.

Comment: Thank you. I understand what you mean now. It works when the parameter is an exact as the array. However,  the "year"  is in "incident_dateTime" ("2017-01-21T00:40:35.000") which consist of date and time. Is there anyway I can have only the year in the "incident_dateTime"  as a parameter?

Comment: Have a look at Just Code's solution. If they do not allow arguments in the URL for filtering on their end, you will have to do it on your end. Look within the `success` function.